# What is the URL format for window.open()?

Tags: jsf-2, window.open

Using h:link, the url format is like this:

```
<h:link value="Printable View" outcome="/pages/printPreview" target="_blank" style="float: right;">
   <f:param name="previewId" value="#{previewBean.preview.id}" />
</h:link>
```

But I want to open the new tab as a popup window, so I use the following code:

```
<h:link id="openPopUp" value="OPEN POPUP" target="blankPopUp"
  onclick="window.open('/pages/printPreview','blankPopUp','menubar=no,width=900,height=690');" 
  action="#{previewBean.renderPreview}">
    <f:param name="previewId" value="#{previewBean.preview.id}" />
</h:link>
```

The result that I get from using `window.open` is actually opening the same page as a popup, it does not redirect me to the URL that I want.

I have tried the following format but still not able to solve the problem.

```
 /pages/printPreview 
 /pages/printPreview.jsf 
 /pages/printPreview.xhtml
 /printPreview 
 /printPreview.jsf 
 /printPreview.xhtml
```

Does anyone can tell me what is the correct URL format to use in `windows.open` ?

Thanks.

Comment: What URL *does* it redirect to, compared to what you want? Is your only problem that you're missing the context-root?

Comment: let say now I'm at pageA, I want to redirect to pageB from pageA.

Comment: What I'm after is a full URL, say pageA is at `http://localhost/myApp/pages/pageA` then you need to `window.open('/myApp/pages/pageB', '_blank', ...)` or try `window.open('pageB', ...)` if pageA is always in the same directory as pageB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have sucussfully open pageB as a popup using 
window.open('pageB.jsf', ...) with <p:commandLink>. But I can't get my parameter using <f: param> with <p: commandLinkg>. Any idea ?

Comment: `window.open` doesn't know about JSF, it just tells your browser to open another window. AFAIK there's no way to tell JSF to open a popup with a specified layout. You can just use `<h:link outcome="pageB" value="View" target="_blank" />` and style the window from pageB. Or add the parameters to the URL in `window.open`.

Comment: It's not different from when doing it using plain vanilla HTML `<a>` element. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator.

Comment: Thanks @mabi and BalusC. I can now use window. open to open a URL with added parameters. Thanks a lot.